# How to find how much of a library is being used inside a Java application?

Tags: java, refactoring

I am working on an existing Java application that uses 34 external jars.

Part of my job is to make the code cleaner and less bloated. I can easily find which library is not used at all by removing it from the path and testing the code.

However, I suspect there are some libraries of which only a small part is used (may be a function or two).

For example, there is a library for some UI building. However, I suspect that in the application code, it used only for one/two of its logging functions. I can actually implement my own version of that function and completely set the application free of that library.

As I cannot manually explore the code, are there any existing tools that can be used to see how much code from a library is being used in the application code?

Comment: By "cannot manually explore the code," do you mean you don't have access to the application's source code?

Comment: Will a  little bit of shell scripting you can extract which packages are most often imported. On the other hand if you put 10 MiB JAR on the CLASSPATH and use only one class from that JAR, you pay (in terms of memory) only for that class, not for the whole JAR. Finally check out http://proguard.sourceforge.net/

Comment: @matts no I mean its impractical because the code base is large

Comment: @TomaszNurkiewicz My main concern is actually the unnecessary increase in size that the jar adds to the application.

Comment: I don't know of any existing tools which can do this, but writing a tool of your own wouldn't be too difficult: it could load the classes of the project and then use a bytecode modification/engineering library such as ASM to scan through methods/superclasses/superinterfaces to discover what libraries are called from the main project, or even from other libraries.  (I might design a simple tool later today to do this; if I do, I'll post it here.)

Comment: Most libraries have only a few "root" package names. And many IDEs allow you to search for usage using wildcards.

Comment: @TomaszNurkiewicz `import` calls don't need to exist (a class can be referenced by its full classpath directly within code), so that wouldn't always work.

Comment: @TomaszNurkiewicz - current JVMs memory-map the classpath JARs, so you will pay 10 Mib plus additional for in-memory class representations. On the other hand, memory is cheap.

Comment: @Ankit Are you sure this is worth the bother that amending the build process and working out any bugs caused by dynamic loading will cause? Unused bits of JARs probably don't meaningfully affect performance once the system reaches a steady state and all the classes that are actually used have been loaded. (Especially if your codebase is large.)

Comment: only 34 external jars? that's not a lot by Java standards. :-)

Answer (score 1):

I would tend to use something like [proguard](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/) to identify old unused code, although it has tons of other features, they're not relevant to your question.

Comment: +1 for ProGuard, which strips out the parts of dependency libraries that are never used.  This really sounds like exactly what the OP actually needs.

Answer (score 1):

[JDepend](http://clarkware.com/software/JDepend.html) can tell you the direct dependencies of your application classes, however this won't really tell you which JARs you can eliminate, for (at least) two reasons:

1. It can only pick up compiled-in class references. If you use a tool like Spring, which lets you specify classes in a non-code configuration file, JDepend (or any other tool) has no way to identify them. Ditto if you manually load a class with `Class.forName`.
2. Your code might not directly reference a class, but something that you load might (Maven calls this a transitive dependency). For example, Hibernate requires either CGLib or Javassist (or at least it used to). If you depend on Hibernate, you implicitly depend on one of those JARs.

In it's probably easiest to start with JDepend, and build with only the JARs that it tells you that you need. Then, during runtime, you'll get class-not-found exceptions that will tell you what additional JARs you need.

Edit:

> As I cannot manually explore the code, are there any existing tools that can be used to see how much code from a library is being used in the application code?

As a reread your question, I realized that you were asking for something more targeted than a simple dependency analysis. I think that a code coverage tool might point you in the right direction. Some open-source possibilities:

- [Emma](http://emma.sourceforge.net/)
- [Cobertura](http://cobertura.sourceforge.net/)

You can instrument your entire application, then run it normally and find out what classes are actually called. *However*, you will need to exercise it *fully*. Java loads classes on an as-needed basis, so your application might depend on a class only for some of its features.

Answer (score 0):

You can search the code and xml for the packages the JARs start with.

I would try removing it from the build and re-build the program and when it compiles test it.

Answer (score 0):

For a quick and dirty strategy, you can opt to write a script to recurse all application code and extract all import, sort them by least to most used, match the base import package structure to a jar then examine where the least imported jars are used.

For better long term analysis, Try and solve these issues first.
To begin with, if you can, best to convert the application use standard build tools e.g. maven.
Next get the application working and building on a standard IDE e.g. eclipse.

Now you can search for and use plugins that can enable you to do what you need to do.

e.g. maven

mvn dependency:analyze

and take a look at eclipse plugins that can do same

e.g.

http://classpathhelper.sourceforge.net/

There is maintainability going forward

This might be extra work upfront but the better you can analyze your code the faster your task will be.
If you want to be a master you could even write an eclipse plugin and share it!